# How to make a Button act like a Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-button

I want a Button pull up a menu like a Spinner but it doesn't need to store data like the prompt in a Spinner.

A Spinner looks like this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.social_list, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item);//select_dialog_multichoice);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

I need to work same thing as a Button... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i  think you should put `spinner.performClick();` on button click method

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of[ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html). 
Here is a link about Context Menu Demo.

http://mobile.dzone.com/news/context-menu-android-tutorial

But little modifications are required. Inside the button click event, you have to open the ContextMenu.

Answer (score 0):

just open the dialog with list on button click will be looks same as spinner .....

as in

http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/05/dialog-list-item.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

use Resources res = getResources();

```
final String[] items = res.getStringArray(R.array.social_list);
//final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

[Android Custom List Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194694/android-custom-list-dialog)